# Adding a column of fake data to a dataframe in pyspark: Unsupported literal type class

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, faker

I'm trying to add an extra new column of fake data to my dataset.  Say this one as an example (it doesn't make a difference what the dataframe is- I need a new extra column with unique, fake names; this is just a dummy to play with):

```
from faker import Faker

faker = Faker("en_GB")

profiles = [faker.profile() for i in range(0, 100)]
profiles = spark.createDataFrame(profiles)
```

And I'm trying to add a new column of first names with one name per row.  At the moment, I'm doing this (I know this won't do what I want it to but I can't figure out what else to do):

```
profiles = profiles.withColumn('first_name', lit([faker.first_name()] for _ in 'name'))
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [[Robin], [Margaret], [Robin], [Victor]]
> I'd like to keep it to one line as that's what I need for further analyses.

I think I understand why I'm getting the error but I'm not sure what to do about it...  Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: what is your expected output ? Currently, you're trying to add the value `[[Robin], [Margaret], [Robin], [Victor]]` (array of arrays of string) to each line of your dataframe.

Comment: I'd like Robin, Margaret etc to each be added to a separate line in the dataframe (edited to add)

Comment: Names are generated randomly, you'll have to use `split` on `name` column and take the first name, but be aware that some names can be in the format: `Mrs Carole Price`. So just splitting on space and taking the first element won't work.

Comment: The names are generated randomly in this dummy dataset but not the actual dataset I'm working.  I can't just split the name column- I need a new column with fake first names

Comment: in profile, you already have ` 'name': 'Ms Diana Mason',` (for example) - but you want to add a first name ? What is stopping you from splitting ?

Comment: profile is a randomly generated dataframe to play around with not the actual dataframe.  It's just a dummy.  Please ignore whatever is in there.  It doesn't make a difference to the column I'm trying to add

Comment: please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question with input/expected output details.

Comment: She needs something like: `profiles = profiles.withColumn("first_name", F.lit(faker.first_name()))`. But the problem with that is that `faker.first_name()` is evaluated once and will produce the same first name for all rows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63269034/using-faker-with-pyspark-dataframe-to-anonymise-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from faker import Faker

faker = Faker("en_GB")

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
profiles = [faker.profile() for i in range(0, 100)]
profiles = spark.createDataFrame(profiles)
fake_names = [faker.first_name() for _ in range(profiles.count())]
profiles = profiles.withColumn(
    "first_name", F.udf(lambda x: fake_names[x])(F.monotonically_increasing_id())
)
```

Fake names need to be generated outside the dataframe. If you use:

```
profiles.withColumn("first_name", F.lit(faker.first_name()))
```

You'll get the same fake name for all rows.

- Edit:

`row_number` example:

```py
fake_names = [faker.first_name() for _ in range(profiles.count())]
window = Window.orderBy("name") # Or any other unique column, but I guess name is unique here
profiles = profiles.withColumn(
    "first_name", F.udf(lambda x: fake_names[x - 1])(F.row_number().over(window))
)
```

Comment: [`monotonically_increasing_id`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) wont work as it is not continous. `The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not consecutive`

Comment: This seems to work and create a column with randomly generated first names!  Thanks :)

Comment: @Steven Yeah, you are right. It's not the best solution.

Comment: @CarolinaKaroullas As Steven mentioned, solution has flaws. But if it works for you I guess it's fine.

Comment: @VladSiv Steven thanks both!  Would either of you mind explaining what the issue actually is?  I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand enough to tell if it works for me or not!

Comment: @Steven (to add you to the above comment)

Comment: @CarolinaKaroullas It's not OK because some of the fake names will repeat. `monotonically_increasing_id` is not continuous and can (in this case) result in batches that repeat. If you have a unique column in your original dataframe, you can create a `Window` over it and use `row_number` to get unique fake names.

Comment: @VladSiv Ah I see that makes sense!  What would it look like if I were to use a window function and ```row_number```?  Would it be the same as in the answer but just replace ```F.monotonically_increasing_id()``` with the window?  Sorry I'm very new to pyspark!

Comment: I think this has worked: ```w = W.partitionBy().orderBy('RowId')``` and ```.withColumn("FstName", F.udf(lambda x: first_names[x])(row_number().over(w)))```? Does this seem right?

Comment: @CarolinaKaroullas yea, I updated the answer and added an example.

Comment: @CarolinaKaroullas yep, this one is better in terms of logic but awful in terms of performance.

Comment: @Steven So I've noticed!  Especially as I have over a million rows!! :')

Comment: @Steven Well, I tried to help. What are the other options for better performance? I'd really like to know. I'm still learning.

Comment: @VladSiv this has definitely helped though!!  Thank you for taking the time to look at it :)  And it does work even if it takes a while (probably also doesn't help that I'm doing this for 12 columns in a dataframe with over 1 million rows...)

Comment: @VladSiv install faker on all the nodes and use `F.udf(faker.first_name())`

Comment: @Steven Yea, if you have access to do that. En tout cas, merci, très apprécié!

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want ?

```py
from faker import Faker

faker = Faker("en_GB")

profiles = [[faker.profile(), faker.first_name()] for i in range(0, 100)]
profiles = spark.createDataFrame(profiles, ["profile", "first_name"])

profiles.show()
```

Comment: Not quite but closer!  I just want to add that "first_name" column to the profiles dataframe (or any other dataframe) as a separate column with one name per row.